# Regularity of derived function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If we are given that a function $u$ in time and space is in $H^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is the space domain. What can we deduce about the regularity go $u_t$ (the derivative if $u$ in time) ? Can we say that $u_t \in H^1(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing can be informed about $u_t$
We can only have information about the first order derivative with respect to $x$, which is in $L^2$